# fatal error: wiringPi.h: No such file or directory

Tags: wiringpi, cross-compilation

Learning cmake for use with CLion. I have a raspberry pi project and I'm trying to bring in wiringPi library on my Ubuntu box. Here's my build results.

```
====================[ Build | rookery_exe | Raspberry Pi Release ]==============
/snap/bin/cmake --build /tmp/tmp.UNnm1OGKQ2/cmake-build-raspberry-pi-release --target rookery_exe -- -j 12
[  9%] Building CXX object src/core/CMakeFiles/rookery_core.dir/Lights.cpp.o
/tmp/tmp.UNnm1OGKQ2/src/core/Lights.cpp:1:10: fatal error: wiringPi.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <wiringPi.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
gmake[3]: *** [src/core/CMakeFiles/rookery_core.dir/build.make:124: src/core/CMakeFiles/rookery_core.dir/Lights.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:203: src/core/CMakeFiles/rookery_core.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:236: src/exe/CMakeFiles/rookery_exe.dir/rule] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:182: rookery_exe] Error 2
```

I installed both libwiringpi and libwiringpi-dev. When I looked, here's the result of my find command:

```
thomas@bravos:/usr$ find -name *wiringPi*
./lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwiringPiDev.so.2
./lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwiringPiDev.so
./lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwiringPi.so.2.50
./lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwiringPi.so
./lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwiringPi.so.2
./lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwiringPiDev.so.2.50
./include/wiringPi.h
./include/wiringPiSPI.h
./include/wiringPiI2C.h
thomas@bravos:/usr$
```

My cmake file is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)

project(rookery_core)

file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES LIST_DIRECTORIES true *.h *.cpp)

set(SOURCES ${SOURCES})

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_library(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_core STATIC ${SOURCES})

target_include_directories(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_core PUBLIC /usr/include ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} )

target_link_directories(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_core INTERFACE /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu)

find_library(LIB_WIRING_PI libwiringPi HINTS /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu)
```

Not sure where to go with this. I took a whole udemy class on cmake.

Comment: Could you edit your post and indicate the result of compiling a minimal wiringPi program with gcc?  It just needs to be dummy main as long as the source includes wiringPi.h.

Comment: @joan, You mean cross compiling or compiling on the raspberry pi itself?

Comment: On your Ubuntu box.  The same as your cmake.  I'm just wondering why the include is not found in your path.

Comment: @joan I have such a program. I'll have to figure out how to build without cmake. Do you have advice? Can I find the build command somewhere in my makefile?

Answer (score 0):

You have installed WiringPi in your Ubuntu machine's `/usr` folder. CMake doesn't look in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` or `/usr/include` when cross-compiling, and it *shouldn't* look there either.

You have to install WiringPi in the sysroot folder you created for cross-compiling.

> I took a whole udemy class on cmake.

If that course teaches people to `GLOB_RECURSE` the source files or to hard-code system paths like `/usr/include`, you might want to forget what you learned there ...

Comment: Those are things I've tried on my own to get this working. By sysroot folder, is that the toolchain folder I created that holds the cross compiler?

Comment: @Thom no, the sysroot is the folder that contains all necessary libraries and headers for cross compilation. Your toolchain comes with a basic sysroot that has glibc etc. Your toolchain's sysroot is (should be) read-only, so you usually create a copy that you install all libraries into for a specific project. From your previous questions, I understand that you are using my RPi-Cpp-Toolchain, it has a brief explanation about sysroots here: https://tttapa.github.io/Pages/Raspberry-Pi/C++-Development/Dependencies.html